# Can google impersonate me and obtain data from third party application

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I just stated reading about OAuth and cannot find an answer to this question.
If I do sign-in with google on an application, then google will tell the application who I am. So is it possible that someone from google i.e. a google employee (assuming he knows my username and password because google has all my data) can impersonate me and get all my data from that application?

Comment: Since Google controls your Google account, they could go through the same login procedure as you do, but impersonate you during the login on Google's site. Then they have the same access to the 3rd party as you do after login.

Comment: @deceze isn't that a security flaw?

Comment: It's a risk you're taking with any 3rd party login system.

Comment: If you do a sign-in with google on an application, let's say an online photo editing app, the app requests an access token to "Read" photos from Google's Authorization server. The Google Auth Server then gives the app an access token with 'read-photo' scope or whatever. Now, the app can request the photos on your behalf and the app has access only to read your photo from Google's Resource server such as Google Drive. 

PS: The photo editing app has to be configured in Google Auth server as an OAuth client. This makes sure that the app is trustable by the Google Auth server

Comment: *"assuming he knows my username and password"* — They don't even need to know your password, in fact they hopefully don't. The chain is 3rd party app requests authentication → the user proves to Google who they are with their username/password → Google tells 3rd party app who you are. As Google, they could skip the second step entirely and simply tell the 3rd party any random username.

Comment: I could see you've edited your question. If Google stores your data, it doesn't mean Google employees know your credentials. They might encrypt your credentials before storing them in the DB or they might have other mechanisms to securely store your credentials in a Google server that no other employees can't use just like that.

Comment: @Kishan They hopefully follow best practices and only store a *hash* of my password, which makes it unknowable. The username/email will need to remain plaintext, as it would otherwise be impossible to find my account information for login.

Comment: @deceze That's correct. Looks like drx835 has misunderstood the OAuth2 workflow. OAuth2 is all about delegating permissions to a 3rd party app to access your data without having to share your credentials with the 3rd party app

Comment: @KishanLal that was never my question. I know the workflow of OAuth but deceze has answered my question